# GET spotify api 403 error. Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, jsx

I am getting the following error:

> GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?type=track&limit=1 403 ()
>
> Uncaught (in promise)  :3000/test/#access_token=...
>
> XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}

here is the respective code:

```
getNowPlaying(){
    spotifyWebApi.getMyRecentlyPlayedTracks({"type":"track", "limit":1})
      .then((response) => { 
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: {
            name: response.items[0].track.name,
            image: response.items[0].track.album.images[0].url
          }
        })
      })
  }
```

this is a different function that i've already used it and works perfectly:

```
getNowPlaying(){
    spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
      .then((response) => { 
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: {
            name: response.item.name,
            image: response.item.album.images[0].url
          }
        })
      })
  }
```

Comment: `The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it` - so, are you trying to use an API you are not authorized to?

Comment: no... I can use `getNowPlaying()` perfectly